# How to mock chain of calls someService.method1().method2()

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mockmvc

for example I have a class

```
class MyClass {
@Autowired
SomeService someService;

@RequestMapping("/somepath")
public Object myMethod(){
  someService.method1().method2();
  //method2 is void
...
}
```

and MvcTest

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyClassTest{
@MockBean
SomeService someService;

@Test
void test1(){
//how should be mocked this methods?
doNothing().when(someService.method1().method2()) //??
final MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(String.format("/somepath")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
}
}
}
```

My question is: how correctly should be mocked this "chain" of methods?

Comment: you can use Mockito doAnswer and then continue your mocking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying that this is recommended nor that it's a good idea, but in this simple case, you can instruct Mockito to have every method [recursively return another mock object](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Answers.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

```
@MockBean(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
SomeService someService;
```

From the [documentation](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> **WARNING**: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code. Mocking a mock to return a mock, to return a mock, (...), to return something meaningful hints at violation of Law of Demeter or mocking a value object (a well known anti-pattern).