# NullPointerException returned when using Mockito when().thenReturn() stubbing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, stubbing

I have this interface:

```
public interface BindingStubHelper {

  public BindingStub getBindingStub()
      throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}
```

This is the implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class BindingStubImpl implements BindingStubHelper {

  @Value("${my.url}")
  private URL url;

  @Override
  public BindingStub getBindingStub()
      throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    BindingStub BindingStub = new BindingStub(url, null);
    return BindingStub;
  }
}
```

I call it in my applicaiton with:

```
@Autowired private BindingStubHelper bindingStub;
...
payments = bindingStub.getBindingStub().generateSchedule(paymentRequest);
```

I have BDD tests where I'm trying to mock the response. In it I have:

```
Payment payments =
        new Payment(
            34.97,
            22.58304,
            0.0,
            0.0,
            534.97,
            0,
            0,
            7.0,
            installmentList,
            500,
            500,
            500,
            500,
            10,
            500,
            0.0,
            20.00);
    PaymentRequest paymentRequest =
        new PaymentRequest(
            500.0,
            startDate,
            renewalDate,
            Source.Annex,
            "838",
            "065714",
            "MQ",
            Type.New);
    when(bindingStubHelper
            .getBindingStub()
            .generatePayments(paymentRequest))
        .thenReturn(payments);
```

I get a `NullPointerException` on the line `.generatePayments(paymentRequest))`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188983/how-to-mock-chain-of-calls-someservice-method1-method2

Comment: If your bindingStubHelper is a mock, then you first define the behavior for the call to `getBindingStub()`, make it return a mock and on that mock, define the behavior for  `.generatePayments(paymentRequest)`.  The NPE is because the call to `getBindingStub` is returning null because you didn't specify the behavior for this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `bindingStubHelper` is a mock, if you expect the call to `.getBindingStub()` to return anything, you'll first have to define what you want it to return.

```
when(bindingStubHelper.getBindingStub()).thenReturn(mockedBindingStub);
```

Now that it's returning a mock, define what should happen when the call to `generatePayments` is made.

```
when(mockedBindingStub.generatePayments(paymentRequest)).thenReturn(payments);
```

Comment: Or specify the `RETURN_DEEP_STUBS` answer option when creating the mock object.

Comment: @knittl Certainly in this case, it will work.  I tend to avoid this because it will not work if you try and perform a verification on the "deep stub"

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `verify(bindingStubHelper.getBindingStub()).generatePayments()` works just as well on a deep stub as it does on a "shallow" (?) stub.

Comment: @knittl Verification only works with the last mock in the chain.  Consider this,
`when(p.getA(anyString()).getB(anyString()).getC()).thenReturn("C");`
`p.getA("A").getB("B").getC();`
`verify(p.getA("WRONG").getB("B")).getC();` where p is a defined as deep mock.  You would expect this to fail because I'm passing "A" to `getA()` and verifying that it was called with "WRONG"; however, this verify works just fine because verify only works on the last mock in the chain.  For this reason, I do not use deep mocks

Comment: Would `when(mockedBindingStub.generatePayments(any())).thenReturn(payments)` work?

Comment: @runnerpaul it will.  Any matcher that matches your parameters will work.  I prefer to be explicit with my matchers, but you don't have to be

Comment: @lane.maxwell ah yes, thanks for the counter example. That's unintutive – but still kind of correct, from Mockito's point of view. The stub was defined to return the same mock for any string argument (`anyString()`), so you are verifying the same `getB("B")` call on the mock object returned by `getA(…)`. If this is not wanted, either stub with `when(p.getA(eq("A").…)` or verify the inner/front call: `verify(p).getA("A"); verify(p.getA("WRONG").getB("B")).getC();` This will fail as expected in your example. Nested verification will fail in exactly the same way with "manual deep stubs".

Comment: @knittl Actually, without using deep mocks, I can define these and perform the proper verifications, even using `anyString()`.  If you want to see it in action, I'll throw together a gist that illustrates the pitfalls.  It's further exacerbated if your logic makes multiple calls to the mock :(